# Is the set of diagonalizable, complex matrices open in the set of square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Is the set of complex, diagonalizable matrices open in the set of square matrices?

I asked myself this question and I tried to prove it somehow. However, I don't have any good approach so far.

What is the best way to prove this?

Comment: What do you mean by quadratic matrices?

Comment: @ploosu2, perhaps "quadratic matrices" = square matrices ....perhaps-perhaps.

Comment: We need to know what "quadratic matrices" are in order to help you

Comment: Oh, sry. What I meant to say was "square matrices".

Comment: Hint: Try looking at an open neighborhood of the identity matrix.

Comment: Imagine a tiny value off of the main diagonal, but still close to it.

Comment: As many people have demonstrated, the set of diagonalizable (complex, $n \times n$) matrices is not open in the set of matrices.  But it is probably worth noting that the set of diagonalizable matrices with distinct eigenvalues is. In fact it is a Zariski-open set. To see this, just note that having repeated eigenvalues is equivalent to the vanishing of the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @heureka and everyone, can I ask how this problem came to OP's mind. I really have no intuition over the normed vector space of matrices and I can't see this problem might be applied somewhere in mathematics ! Thank

Comment: Until today I've just used the norms over the matrices to control some terms in Analysis; such as $||A(v-v')||\leq M||v-v'||$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the set of diagonalizable matrices is not open:

the matrix    $  \begin{pmatrix}    1 &\epsilon\\    0 & 1            \end{pmatrix}        $ is diagonalizable only if $\epsilon=0$ .
[Reason: if such a matrix is diagonalizable its diagonalization must be $I$, the unit matrix, because the only eigenvalue is $1$  and the matrix $I$ is similar only to itself]

**Edit: arbitrary fields**
The above is meant implicitly  over  $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ with their usual metric topology, but more algebraically minded users may take as ground field an arbitrary field with its Zariski(=cofinite) topology.

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary open ball around the identity matrix. This will contain matrices that have $1$ on the diagonal and $\epsilon$ on the second diagonal above the diagonal for $\epsilon > 0 $, if $\epsilon$ if sufficiently small. This is a scalar multiple of the Jordan normal form of a matrix that cannot be diagonalized (putting $1/\epsilon$ on the diagonal and $1$ on the second diagonal). So no, your set of diagonalizable matrices is not open.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: assuming we're talking of $\;M_n(\Bbb C)\;$ embedded in $\;C^{n^2}\;$ and with the inherited topology there, let us look at

$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;\;,\;\;\;A_n:=\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac1n&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&0&\ldots& 0\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\0&0&0&\ldots&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Obviously $\;\{A_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\rlap\subset{\,/}\;Diag_n(\Bbb C)\;$, yet $\;A_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0_n\in Diag_n(\Bbb C)\;$ , so...